# Differentiating a vector product

Tags: angular-momentum, vectors, rotational-kinematics

$$m_i\mathbf{r}_i\times\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\mathbf{r}_i}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\biggl(m_i\mathbf{r}_i\times\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}_i}{\mathrm{d}t}\biggr)$$

I do not understand this. How did the $\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}t$ go out?

Comment: Use Leibnitz's product rule and then take heed that the cross product of anything with itself is nought.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a identity for the derivative of the cross-product of two vector functions $\mathbf A(t)$ and $\mathbf B(t)$;
\begin{align}
  \frac{d}{dt} (\mathbf A \times \mathbf B) = \frac{d\mathbf A}{dt}\times \mathbf B + \mathbf A\times \frac{d\mathbf B}{dt}
\end{align}
Using this rule with the computation you're considering, we obtain
\begin{align}
  \frac{d}{dt}\left(m_i\mathbf r_i\times \frac{d\mathbf r_i}{dt}\right)
  = m_i \frac{d\mathbf r_i}{dt}\times \frac{d\mathbf r_i}{dt} + m_i\mathbf r_i\times \frac{d^2\mathbf r_i}{dt^2}
  = m_i\mathbf r_i\times \frac{d^2\mathbf r_i}{dt^2}
\end{align}
where in the last step, we have used the fact that the cross product of any vector with itself is zero.

Comment: proove that identity?

Comment: @vardhanamdaga Are you familiar with the levi-civita symbol and writing the cross product in terms of it?

Comment: nopes. No other simpler way?

Comment: @vardhanamdaga There are, but they are more algebraically intensive.  See, for example, George Jones' answer here http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=106405 .  You'll find a lot of other proofs by googling this btw.

Comment: The proof follows from bilinearity of the cross product. Sketch of proof: $A(t+\Delta t) \times B(t+\Delta t) = (A(t) +\dot{A} \Delta t) \times (B(t) +\dot{B} \Delta t) = A(t) \times B(t) + A(t) \times \dot{B}(t) \Delta t +  \dot{A}(t) \times B(t) \Delta t + \dot{A}(t) \times \dot{B}(t) (\Delta t)^2$. We see the first order piece is $A(t) \times \dot{B}(t) \Delta t +  \dot{A}(t) \times B(t) \Delta t$, so the derivative is $A(t) \times \dot{B}(t) + \dot{A}(t) \times B(t)$. Similar proofs could be used for any multilinear function.

Answer (score 4):

1. The vector product of a vector $\vec{a}$ with itself is alwals zero: $\vec{a} \times \vec{a} = 0$
2. For two smooth vector-valued functions $\vec{a},\vec{b} \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ the product rule holds:

$$
\frac{d}{dt} (\vec{a} \times \vec{b}) = \frac{d}{dt} \vec{a} \times \vec{b} + \vec{a} \times \frac{d}{dt} \vec{b}
$$

You can see this for example, if you write out the components (then it is just the ordinary product rule).

Take for example the first component:

$$
\begin{align}
\left (\frac{d}{dt} (\vec{a} \times \vec{b}) \right)_1 &= \frac{d}{dt} (a_2b_3 - a_3 b_2)\\ &= \frac{d}{dt}(a_2b_3) - \frac{d}{dt}(a_3 b_2)\\ &= \left(\frac{d}{dt}a_2\right) b_3 + a_2 \frac{d}{dt} b_3 - \left(\frac{d}{dt}a_3\right) b_2 - a_3 \frac{d}{dt} b_2\\ &= \left(\frac{d}{dt}a_2\right) b_3 - \left(\frac{d}{dt}a_3\right) b_2 + a_2 \frac{d}{dt} b_3 - a_3 \frac{d}{dt} b_2 \\ &=  \left(\frac{d}{dt} \vec{a} \times \vec{b}\right)_1 + \left(\vec{a} \times \frac{d}{dt} \vec{b}\right)_1
\end{align}
$$

Putting this together you get your result:

$$
  \frac{d}{dt}\left(m_i \vec{r}_i\times \frac{d \vec{r}_i}{dt}\right)
  = m_i \frac{d \vec{r}_i}{dt}\times \frac{d \vec{r}_i}{dt} + m_i \vec{r}_i\times \frac{d^2\vec{r}_i}{dt^2}
  = m_i\vec{r}_i\times \frac{d^2\vec{r}_i}{dt^2}
$$